Test between model output over a binary variable
I have a set of features that includes a binary variable (called $B$) and some others ( binary or numerical variables, let's these covariates $X$).
I have a target variable that can be either binary or numerical, but let's keep it simple and say it's numerical and called $Y$.
I fit a model $M$ to predict $Y$ over the features $X$ and $B$. The model can be 'optimized' or rubbish, it does not matter. The fact is that the model is fitted.
Now I predict (using the same training data or some unseen test data, I don't think it really changes the problem ?) two quantities.

$Y_{B=1}$ is when for an individual, I keep as it is the covariates $X$ but I force the binary feature $B$ to be $1$ (even if the actual value of $B$ for the individual is not $1$).
$Y_{B=0}$ is when for an individual, I keep as it is the covariates $X$ but I force the binary feature $B$ to be $0$.

Then I want to know if on average these two quantities are different. So whether, statistically, $Y_{B=1} = Y_{B=0}$ or not (which is equivalent to $Y_{B=1} - Y_{B=0} = 0$), and get a p-value on that hypothesis.
For-example with a simple linear regression without interaction terms, I can check the coefficient for $B$ and associated p-value (and the difference $Y_{B=1} - Y_{B=0}$ is always the same in this case and equals to the $B$ coefficient).
But for more complex models (Random Forest, etc), there usually are some interactions.
So, my question is : which statistical test (or tests) seems appropriate ?

Data are not independant ($Y_{B=1}$ and $Y_{B=0}$ still relies on the same model $M$ and covariates $X$).
Variance between the groups ($B=1$ and $B=0$) may be different.

I looked for estimation of treatment effects (ATE, ATT, etc) but did not find a clear explanations of which test I could use, since often in those cases a simple linear regression model is used.
